# I'd known nothing "until", "when", or "before" I read that article

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I read an article about Taj Mahal in India yesterday. Before reading this article, I knew nothing about it. Here are three sentences:

> I'd known nothing about Taj Mahal UNTIL I read that article yesterday.
>
> I'd known nothing about Taj Mahal BEFORE I read that article
> yesterday.
>
> I'd known nothing about Taj Mahal WHEN I read that article yesterday.

I think WHEN is wrong. Is BEFORE or UNTIL correct?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want to use past perfect "I had known"? Past simple would be OK. "I knew".

Comment: In English, we say **the** Taj Mahal.

Comment: Either _until_ or _before_ is acceptable.

Comment: I can see *when* being OK too, if I were trying to describe my particular experience of reading the article.